# Software for visualizing wiring of components

Tags: data-visualization, diagram, component-diagram

I am looking for a smart and convenient software which can be used to visualize components (blocks) and their wirings. For this task we currently use `CorelDRAW` which is okay but too universal for this use case.

The main problem is, that each wire and each block has to be drawn separately, by hand. If a wire changes it has to be manually deleted and manually added again. Also style tends to be not uniform when multiple developer edit the same diagram over time.

It would be more convenient if there was a program, which takes an XML file or similar, where each block and its relationship to the other blocks is defined.

Below is an example of how two blocks could look and their wiring. It does not need any electrical information, it's just about the raw relationship between the blocks.

Are there any ready-to-go software solutions for this?

[image]